# How does projective geometry related with Fourier transform via Lorentz transformation?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, relativity, fourier-transform, lorentz-symmetry, geometry

On one hand, the [Lorentz transformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh0pYtQG5wI) plays an [important role](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity) in classical electromagnetism. On the other hand, each Lorentz tranformation is also a [Möbius transformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY) of $\Bbb C$ (Needham, *Visual Complex Analysis*):

$$M(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

But what is the direct link between projective geometry and Fourier transform in physics? Can changing the perspective give rise to [uncertainty principle](https://www.3blue1brown.com/videos/2018/2/25/uncertainty-principle-its-not-about-quantum)? My knowledge is not very solid, but I guess we would start from the $U(1)$ group in QED then use the [Peter - Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem), but exactly where Möbius transformation plays a role in there? If possible, I'd like to have an intuitive answer.

<sup>Related:

• [What projective groups whose characters form the basis of their corresponding $L^2$ space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2799499/157643) on Math

• [Same question asked on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/8qyacf/how_does_projective_geometry_related_with_fourier/?st=jiepb0az&sh=903c0c54)</sup>

Comment: I think what you're looking for is there is a translation subgroup in the Mobius group for which you can define a transform acting on $L^2 (\mathbb{CP}^1)$ (plug in $z=-d/c$ into the formula). This subgroup becomes a subgroup for Lorentz transformations and you can break up $L^2 (\mathbb{R}^{3,1})$ with respect to this subgroup. It's not a translation subgroup, so not a Fourier transform, but it is "something". Is that what you are asking?

Comment: What is $L^2(\Bbb{R}^{3,1})$? The theorem makes sure that with any locally compact group there will be a generalized Fourier transform, so why not in this case? Again, my understanding is very rough, so an intuitive answer is very appreciated

Comment: Yes, there will be a generalized Fourier transform but it won't match with the regular Fourier transform at all. But if it looks like I have interpreted the question correctly, then tell me and I could put a longer explanation into an answer.

Comment: yes, I just need to see the link between the (generalized?) Möbius transform connects with the (generalized) Fourier transform. The problem is that I see both connect with the Lorentz transform so I think there is a physical thing in that link. I wonder if there is a physical application for the generalized ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the subgroup $PSL(2,\mathbb{C}) \simeq SO^+(1,3)$. So yes we can take the subgroup given by the classes of the following elements

$$
P_b = \begin{pmatrix}
1&b\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with $b$ real.

Under the specified isomorphism this becomes

$$
Q=\begin{pmatrix}
t+z&x-iy\\
x+iy&t-z
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
P_b Q P_b^\dagger\\
= \begin{pmatrix}
 t+2bx+b^2 t + (1-b^2) z & x+bt-bz-i y\\
 x+bt-bz+i y & t-z \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
x \to x+bt-bz\\
y \to y\\
t \to bx+(1+\frac{b^2}{2})t - \frac{b^2}{2} z\\
z \to \frac{b^2}{2} t+(1-\frac{b^2}{2})z+b x
$$

This therefore acts on functions on $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ by acting on the underlying space. So that function space is a representation of this $P_b$ group. We can try to decompose it by characters.

Recall the usual Fourier transform. You have the translation action $x \to x+a$ and the characters of that are the functions $e^{ipx}$ which the function gets decomposed into. They are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $e^{ipa}$ under this transformation.

So take the formula for $P_b Q P_b^\dagger$ and find the analogs for $e^{i p x}$.

See the part of the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) on parabolic transformations. In particular the sorts of functions that are invariant under this group are given. Those are the ones with eigenvalue $0$ so replace that procedure with other eigenvalues.

But you can see unlike a simple translation and Fourier transform, this is not as intuitive of a transformation. There the two sides were position translations and momentum easily interpreted. Here on one side is this explicit mix of rotations and boosts. Send $b \to \epsilon$, if you want the infinitesimal transformation to write the analog of $\frac{d}{dx} f = ip f$. The other side is the corresponding conserved charge for that 1-parameter group.

The $U(1)$ QED group is a separate group. That refers to an internal symmetry not a symmetry of spacetime. $\psi (t,x,y,z) \to e^{i \theta} \psi (t,x,y,z)$. $(t,x,y,z)$ don't change. That abelian group does not move points around, this abelian group does.

For an [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations), you just need two operators that don't commute acting on your Hilbert space. But the Hilbert space is something that should be assigned to a timelike slice. This is mixing up different slices.

Comment: I still not fully understand your answer, but I just find out that there is a [representation theory of the Galilean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Galilean_group), which I think it's closer to what I'm looking for (nonrelativistic mechanics), and perhaps simpler and more connected to the regular Fourier transform? Can you have some comments on that? Thanks